# Matlab plot ax+by+c=0 when a==0 or b==0

Tags: matlab, plot

I am doing a sequence of arithmetic operations to determine the line equation and plot it with `ezplot`. But bad things happen when `a` or `b = 0`. I would like to save line equation with `0` in it (like `5*x+0*y-1=0`), but `y` dissapears, o find another workaround.

**Edit**
Here an example of my code:

```
syms x y
hold on
for i = -1:0.5:1
    for j = -1:0.5:1
        ezplot(i*x+j*y+1, [0,10,0,10])
        pause
    end
end
```

I could draw lines manually when `a` or `b = 0`, but I want more general approach.

Comment: What bad things happen? What is your code? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: It's not much of a code. Its statements; statements; statements; ezplot(f, [0,10]). For instance if there is no coefficient by x (a), then ezplot interprets coefficient by y (b) as the a and switch axis. ezplot also changes min max values and I can't specify them because there is only 1 variable remaining.

Comment: Even with your comment, it is not very clear, what your problem/error is. Can you please post a [minimal working example](http://sscce.org/) which reproduces your problem? (In other words, I want to copy/paste the code from your question to my Matlab, run it and see the error you see).

Comment: syms x y
hold on
for i = -1:0.5:1;
for j = -1:0.5:1;
ezplot(i*x+j*y+1, [0,10,0,10])
pause
end
end

Comment: I could draw lines manually when a or b is 0, but I want more general approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not understand your question, but when I run your example, I get the following error for the third iteration:

> Error using figure
>   Single input must be an existing figure handle or a scalar
>   integer from 1 to 2147483646
>
> Error in ezplot>determineAxes (line 563)
>          figure(fig);
>
> Error in ezplot>ezplot1 (line 449)
>          cax = determineAxes(fig);
>
> Error in ezplot (line 145)
>                  [hp, cax] = ezplot1(cax, f{1}, vars, labels,
>                  args{:});
>
> Error in sym/ezplot (line 72)
>        h = ezplot(fhandle(f),[y(1) y(2)],[y(3) y(4)]);
>
> Error in minimal_example (line 7)
>          ezplot(i*x+j*y+1, [0,10,0,10])

(The next time you ask, please include this kind of information).
What happens is, that for the case of - in your code `i` or `j` but in your question `a` or `b` - either `x` or `y` being multiplied by `0` you now provide too many input arguments. One of them is interpreted as a figure handle and therefore the evaluation cannot continue (because there is no figure with a handle of `0` - all figures have an integer value as handle, hence the error).
The following code mitigates that, by providing a figure handle to `ezplot`. Also, I have changed `i` and `j` to `a` and `b` to correspond to the nomenclature in your question:

```
syms x y

% define a figure and return the handle, f1
f1=figure;

% after initializing the figure, set hold on
hold on

for a = -1:0.5:1
    for b = -1:0.5:1
        % pass the figure handle, f1, to ezplot:
        ezplot(a*x+b*y+1, [0,10,0,10],f1)
        pause
    end
end
```

Now, you will get all lines in your plot.

**Edit**

In the case of `a=0` or `b=0` you might get unexpected results, because the equation is evaluated before it is passed to `ezplot`. Hence `0*y` will cause it to vanish from the evaluation. You can bypass this behaviour by instead of using `0`, using the [floating point relative accuracy `eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html):

```
syms x y

% define a figure and return the handle, f1
f1=figure;

% after initializing the figure, set hold on
hold on

for a = -1:0.5:1
    for b = -1:0.5:1
        % pass the figure handle, f1, to ezplot:
        % add eps to a and b so that the will be as close to zero
        %    as possible but not truly zero
        ezplot((a+eps)*x+(b+eps)*y+1, [0,10,0,10],f1);
        pause
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, figure fixed the range of the axis. Another problem still exists, though. When one variable is absent, another automatically takes place of x axe. I would like them to remain in the same place through all iterations (0*y+1*x+1 = 0 becomes y = x + 1 instead of x = -1).

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I wanted